# Uploaded canvas image is much larger than its primary source

Tags: javascript, php, image, canvas

```
<img id='imgt' src='01.jpg' alt='img'>
```

this image is in original `4000x3000px` - `0.9MB` - computed by css on `960x540px`

**js**

```
    var img = document.getElementById("imgt");
    c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");

    var a = $('#imgt').width();
    var b = $('#imgt').height();

    c1.width = a;
    c1.height = b;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, a, b);

    var dataURL = c1.toDataURL();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'process.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'imgBase64': dataURL},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('ok');
    }
});
```

**process.php**

```
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = 'photo.jpg';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```

Starting image `imgt` is `4000x3000px` - `0.9MB`. Resulting image `photo.jpg` is `960x540px` - `1.05MB`

I suspect that the resulting image is not `jpg` but `png` in fact, so I tried in js instead of `var dataURL = c1.toDataURL()`:

```
var dataURL = c1.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

also

```
var dataURL = c1.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.95);
```

In both cases resulting image is about 200KB but not readable in img viewer - it reports damaged image or something like that.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion was right. When you use only `var dataURL = c1.toDataURL();` the image is saved as `png` by default. To save the image as `jpeg` with reduced quality *(size)*, you do need to use `var dataURL = c1.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.95);`. But the actual issue occurred when you tried to parse / decode the image on the server side. You were trying to replace `data:image/png;base64,`, which is only applicable when the image is in `png` format. Since you're trying to save the image as `jpeg` hence, you need to use `data:image/jpeg;base64,`. So, the server side code would be ...

```
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = 'photo.jpg';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
```